# How to resolve the WPML translation issue on website?

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml

I have one site in **WordPress + DIVI + WooCommerce + WPML** and other plugins.

I am facing one issue on site while WPML Translation.

**Website is in 3 languages:**

- Dutch (Main)
- Franch
- English

**I need to keep different string for different language for the button text in one module of the DIVI.**

I selected English language from adminbar

When I go to **Theme Builder -> Global Header** and I change the **button text to "XYZ"**, **it is reflecting only on English page, that is fine.**

Now when I change the **language to Dutch**
and When I go to **Theme Builder -> Global Header** and I change the button **text to "ABC", then it is reflecting on Dutch and French pages** (English page is fine with "XYZ"), **this must reflect on Dutch page only If I change the button by selecting the Dutch language**

Now when I change the language to French
and When I go to **Theme Builder -> Global Header** and I change the button **text to "DEF"**, then it is reflecting on Dutch and French pages (English page is fine with "XYZ"), this must reflect on French page only If I change the button by selecting the French language

I checked for String Translation, and updated translation for Dutch and French but it is not reflecting on front side.

Answer (score 0):

When you're switching languages and modifying it manually like this, you are messing up the WPML logic that's handling translations. Page builders are tricky to translate. That's why you need to follow the recommended process.

From [documentation](https://wpml.org/documentation/theme-compatibility/divi-builder/#translating-custom-global-header-footer):

> To translate the Divi site header or footer you created using the Divi
> Theme Builder, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to WPML > Translation Management. Choose Header Layout, Footer Layout, or Body Layout from the Type dropdown, then click the Filter
>    button.
> 2. Choose which headers or footers you want to translate, the languages you want to translate them into, and click Translate
>    selected content.
> 3. Go to WPML > Translations to take and translate the global header using the Advanced Translation Editor.

Try this with a fresh site with a new global Divi header/footer from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @montrealist. I tried to follow your process but I am geting nothing on first step. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s6bkWO4z0qHiOruuPKoSI5-MFu5KlIyb/view?usp=sharing